# Friendly url with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have an URL like this

```
http://localhost/rilo/listing.php?id=2
```

where "rilo" is the root and I'd like to get friendly URL like

```
http_//localhost/rilo/listing/2.html
```

And here's the htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rilo

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?listing/([a-zA-Z_]+).html$ listing.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can you help me? Where is the error?

Comment: You haven't told us what it is you want to happen / what actually is happening.

Comment: Sorry Oliver, I've edited my request

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rilo

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?listing/([^.]+)\.html$ listing.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[^/]+/(listing)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.